# SQL Query Optimization with NOT IN statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Please help me optimize this query:

```
$result = mysql_query('
SELECT DISTINCT caseNumber 
FROM master_break 
WHERE invoiceNumber='$invoice' 
AND bay='$bay' AND  caseNumber 
NOT IN( SELECT DISTINCT caseNumber 
        FROM shipped_data 
        WHERE status='' AND bay='$bay') 
        ORDER BY caseNumber ASC");
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where did the `"` at the end come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DISTINCT` means that for each record added to the result set, MySQL has to check the entire set for its existence before adding the record. This means that it has a O(n^2) to insert. When using it in an `IN` clause, this can mean that you're adding substantially more work for zero benefit. Try this instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT caseNumber 
FROM master_break 
WHERE invoiceNumber='$invoice' 
AND bay='$bay' 
AND caseNumber NOT IN( 
     SELECT caseNumber 
     FROM shipped_data 
     WHERE status='' AND bay='$bay') 
ORDER BY caseNumber ASC
```

Obviously index caseNumber on shipped_data, and bay on both.

Comment: dear cwallenpoole, i updated index as you mentioned above.. thanks it working fine and more fast.. please explain how indexes are working here.

Comment: indexes are shortcuts which let your queries run faster. Think of them as really fast look-up tables

Comment: it is possible to do all columns as indexes. how can i select columns for indexing.

Comment: There is not enough room in comments to really address that.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT caseNumber
FROM master_break
LEFT JOIN shipped_data ON master_break.caseNumber = shipped_data.caseNumber
WHERE invoiceNumber='$invoice'
  AND master_break.bay='$bay'
  AND shipped_data.status !=''
  AND shipped_data.bay !='$bay'
ORDER BY caseNumber ASC
```